# How can seeding data in production server - Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have made a db seeder. And used command for data seed:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder
```

Its perfectly working in `localhost`. Now i want to generate demo data into production server. Is there any way how i run this `artisan` command? Or tell me how can i load demo data into database table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably there's a command line interface you can use to access the production server as well?

Comment: @apokryfos I don't understand what are you trying to say. Could you tell me more?

Comment: do you have command line access available to you for that server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the `php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder` command on localhost your doing that in your terminal / console right?

You have to find your console on your web server and run the command from there. When your using a dedicated or VPS server this should be easy. When you have shared hosting it can be a little tricky, so you might need to contact your host to ask if something is possible.

So step by step:

1. Go to the terminal from your server
2. Navigate to your laravel project
3. Run the command

EDIT: You can also run the command on localhost and export the database. And than import it on your host. It's not the best option (And I recommend using the terminal!), but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are using a shared hosting server with som kind of ftp for file transferring. Because if you would have a terminal on your production server, you would've known how to execute commands on them.

If you do have a VPS or dedicated server, you can log in with SSH and execute the command just like you normally would. It could be possible that you get a warning to protect you from seeding in a production environment. But you could simply answer `yes` to continue seeding.